# ExNavigation - Access navigator from parent component or from renderRight

Tags: navigation, react-native

I'm using [ExNavigation](https://github.com/exponentjs/ex-navigation) in my [Exponent](https://getexponent.com) project.

How can I do the navigation from outside the route components?

So from the same place I create

```
<NavigationProvider router={router}>
    <StackNavigation initialRoute={router.getRoute('First')}/>
</NavigationProvider>
```

I want access to a `navigator` so that I can `push` and `pop`.

Another option is to push from inside `First` component, but I'm doing that in `renderRight` component, which is declared inside my `static route` so I don't have access to `this.props.navigator`.

I also want a way to pass props to the route components from the parent (who declares the `<NavigationProvider>...`).

Is any of this possible?

Note: I do not wanna use the Redux store for this. Obviously I can achieve anything with a global function.

Answer (score 1):

*Another option is to push from inside First component, but I'm doing that in renderRight component, which is declared inside my static route so I don't have access to this.props.navigator.*

You can access `this.props.navigator` by using `@withNavigation` decorator. Here's an example of `LogoutButton` button, which you can use in `renderRight`.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {AsyncStorage, Button} from "react-native";
import Router from "../../Router";
import {withNavigation} from "@exponent/ex-navigation/src/ExNavigationComponents";

@withNavigation
export default class LogoutButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Button
            title='Log out'
            onPress={()=>{this.doLogout()}}/>
    )
  }

  doLogout() {
    AsyncStorage.clear();
    this.props.navigator.immediatelyResetStack([Router.getRoute('login')], 0)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this from your 'First' component. And you will have to use event emitter to emit a clicked event from renderRight button, catch that event in your First component and push new route from there. You'll be able to pass props using this too. Here is the solution.

First define the renderRight button class.

```
var EventEmitter = require('EventEmitter');

class NextButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.nextPressed = this.nextPressed.bind(this);
    this.getView = this.getView.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      this.getView()
    );
  }

  getView() {

      return (
        <TouchableHighlight
          onPress={this.nextPressed}
          underlayColor='transparent'
          style={Styles.rightBarButton}>
          <Text
          style={[Styles.rightBarButtonText, Styles.fontStyle, {color:'#6A6A6A'}]}>Next</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      );
  }

  nextPressed() {
    console.log("nextPressed CALLED!");
    this.props.emitter.emit('nextpressed');
  }
}
```

Then use this as your renderRight button inside 'First component'. Also, you need to catch the fired event and push the next component.

```
class First extends Component {

  static route = {
    navigationBar: {
      title: 'FIRST SCREEN',
      titleStyle: [Styles.navigationBarTitle, Styles.fontStyle],
      tintColor: '#000',
      renderRight: ({ config: {eventEmitter} }) => (<NextButton emitter={eventEmitter}/>)
    },
  }

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.pressedEventCallback = this.pressedEventCallback.bind(this);
}

...

componentWillMount() {

   this._buttonPressSubscription = this.props.route.getEventEmitter().addListener('nextpressed', this.pressedEventCallback);
}

componentWillUnmount() {

    this._buttonPressSubscription.remove();
  }

...

  pressedEventCallback() {
    this.props.navigator.push(Router.getRoute('Second', {prop1: prop1, prop2: prop2}));
  }

...
}
```

This way, you can fire event from buttons, catch then in your component and then navigate to other screens passing props along or do whatever you can. Let me know if it works for you.